# Duplicating a mysql row with null variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a lot of columns. I have a function that duplicates my record into a new row with an updated auto-incremented ID.

The function works perfectly however, on some of my INT columns, sometimes I have a NULL as the default. When the record is duplicated, it turns my NULL placement into a 0.

I'm assuming it's because I am doing `'" . value . "'`

Could anyone help me figure out how I could make NULL values be inserted as `" . NULL . "` and keep my other values as `'" . value . "'`?

**EDIT** I'm having trouble differentiating a null and a blank value.  I've tried empty() and is_null() and a varchar with no value and an INT with a NULL value isn't showing a difference

**note**: *I understand that I am using an outdated mysql extension. For right now, I'm just trying to process my null variables correctly.*

```
function duplicateRow($table, $id_field, $id_value)
{
    // copy content of the record you wish to clone 
    $entity = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$id_field}={$id_value}"), MYSQL_ASSOC) or die("Could not select original record"); 

    // set the auto-incremented id's value to blank. If you forget this step, nothing will work because we can't have two records with the same id 
    $entity[$id_field] = ""; 

    // insert cloned copy of the original record 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} (".implode(", ",array_keys($entity)).") VALUES ('".implode("', '",array_values($entity))."')") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //returns the new id
    return mysql_insert_id(); 
}
```

Comment: You've got everything very dynamic here, and thats great, but when you want to start being specific with how values are handled in your field, you have to give up some of that dynamicness.  Specify fields and coalesce them to a string of 'NULL', or change `. value .` to handle nulls.

Comment: I didn't write this function so I'm having trouble breaking down what's going on @paqogomez

Comment: Why don't use just use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: @eggyal I'm confused, Is that not what I'm doing? If you could show me an example that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fetch the data into PHP only then to send it back to MySQL: [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) is a single SQL command that enables the whole shebang to take place natively within the database.

However, you need to exclude the `$id_field` from the operation, so you can't use the `*` wildcard but must instead explicitly list the column names.  This adds some complexity, especially to perform the operation in a safe, injection-proof way:

```
function duplicateRow($table, $id_field, $id_value)
{
    // prevent SQL injection
    $enc_map = array(
      'utf8'   => 'UTF-8',
      'latin1' => 'Windows-1252' // etc.
    );
    mb_regex_encoding($enc_map[mysql_client_encoding()]);
    $table_safe    = '`'.mb_ereg_replace('`', '``', $table   ).'`';
    $id_field_safe = '`'.mb_ereg_replace('`', '``', $id_field).'`';
    $id_value_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($id_value);

    // fetch column names
    $fields = array();
    $qry = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_safe");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
      if ($row['field'] != $id_field)
        $fields[] = '`'.mb_ereg_replace('`', '``', $row['field']).'`';

    $fields_safe = implode(',', $fields);

    // duplicate the record
    mysql_query("
      INSERT INTO $table_safe
        ($fields_safe)
      SELECT $fields_safe
      FROM   $table_safe
      WHERE  $id_field_safe = '$id_value_safe'
    ");

    //returns the new id
    return mysql_insert_id(); 
}
```

Note that the ancient ext/mysql extension has been deprecated and its use in new code has been discouraged for years.  You should *seriously* consider switching to either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Do you know how I would use the "prepare" statement in PDO to make this query more secure than just executing it? `"INSERT INTO {$table} (".implode(", ",array_keys($entity)).") VALUES ('".implode("', '",array_values($entity))."')"` @eggyal

Comment: @user3566265: Prepared statements can only parameterise literal values (such as `$id_value` in this example) - they cannot parameterise object identifiers such as table or field names.

Answer (score 0):

What is your MySQL Version? some versions of MySQL (5.5 and earlier if I'm not mistaken) convert null values to empty for string fields and 0 to int fields.

You have to force null value or update to MySQL 5.6

Comment: Is there an option to force a null or do I need to specify that in my code? I'm using 5.5

Comment: Better way is to specify in your code to avoid future MySQL upgrade errors with default values.

Comment: I'm having trouble differentiating a null and a blank value.  I've tried empty() and is_null() and a varchar with no value and an INT with a NULL value isn't showing a difference

Comment: Have you tried comparison with '===' ? Can you assume that empty values from your original select are null?

You can try change your select to make an INSERT SELECT like

    INSERT INTO table_a (filed_1, field_2, field_n) SELECT field_1, field_2, field_n FROM table_a WHERE id = ?

Note that you have to ommit your primary key field (I tried this with MySQL 5.6 and works fine)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a `foreach` statement that checked to see if my value was null and changed the query a little bit. This may not be the greatest, the right, or practical way to do this but it works. If anyone has any suggestions, they are 100% appreciated!

The reason I kept my function mostly the same is I needed to use this for multiple large tables. So I didn't know exactly what the fields were going to be.

```
function duplicateRow($table, $id_field, $id_value)
{
    // copy content of the record you wish to clone 
    $entity = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$id_field}={$id_value} AND snapshot=0"), MYSQL_ASSOC) or die("Could not select original record"); 

    foreach ($entity as &$value) { if(is_null($value) == true) { $value = "NULL"; } else { $value = "'$value'"; } }

    // set the auto-incremented id's value to blank. If you forget this step, nothing will work because we can't have two records with the same id 
    $entity[$id_field] = "'"; 

    // insert cloned copy of the original record 
    $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} (".implode(", ",array_keys($entity)).") VALUES ('".implode(", ",array_values($entity)).")";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    //returns the new id
    return mysql_insert_id(); 
}
```